# Python Django : Saving a Version model that references other current models saved

Tags: python, django, save, models

I'm really new to Python and Python Django.

I'd like to ask if there's a possibility that I create a `Version` model that saves the state of the other current models that it uses.

For example, there are already entries in models `Point and Line` once I click on a save button, it should create the `Version` model that will contain the state of the current `Point and Line` `data entries, name, date` it was saved. Which, after saving the version, I can still modify my `Point and Line`.

It should be able to create a lot of Versions. Not override one another. What is the best way to do this? Is this even possible?

Would this code be okay?

```
class Version(models.Model):
  prototype_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
  point = models.ForeignKey(Point, on delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  line = models.ForeignKey(Line, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Or I should just create new instances for them.... It seems to be a weird approach...

Comment: I think you you are looking for this https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

Comment: I use https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for similar kind of use case.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev thank you I will be reading this!

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal thank you too! I'll read up on this!